# Asciidoctor: How to add Google Analytics code to all HTML pages with asciidoctor-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, google-analytics, asciidoc, asciidoctor

How do I add Google Analytics (or Google Tag Manager) code to all HTML pages generated by Asciidoctor? There is [an extension](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/blob/master/lib/google-analytics-postprocessor.rb), but that's not available from the maven repository. I am using the `asciidoctor-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `index-docinfo-footer.html` if your file is `index.adoc` in the same directory and add `:docinfo:` in that adoc file.

Fill that footer file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dataLayer = [{'channel' : '{html-googleTagManagerChannel}', 'additional_tracking_code' : '{html-googleAnalyticsId}'}];
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','{html-googleTagManagerId}');</script>
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id={html-googleTagManagerId}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

And then do something like this in your pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
      <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <attributes>
          <html-googleAnalyticsId>UA-123456789-1</html-googleAnalyticsId>
          <html-googleTagManagerId>GTM-ABCDE</html-googleTagManagerId>
          <html-googleTagManagerChannel>MyProject</html-googleTagManagerChannel>
        </attributes>
      </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the extension is published on [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/), you can download the dependency with the [TorqueBox RubyGems Maven Proxy Repository](http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/).

Have a look at the [asciidoctor-pdf-with-theme-example](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/asciidoctor-pdf-with-theme-example) in the asciidoctor maven examples.